# Save individual csv files containing tables using Camelot.py without overwriting

Tags: loops, csv, pdf, python-camelot

I am struggeling trying to make a code, that can extract a table from a pdf and save it to a csv file in a loop.

In my folder I have around 250 pdf files that each contain a table I would like to extract and put in a csv file. I am using Camelot.py for the extracting of the table and the program works perfect with an individual file.

I would like the program to extract the table from the pdf and then save a csv file with the same filename as the pdf containing the table. I have tried to construct a code (see below), that loops through the pdf.files but I am unable to save the output from each pdf.file into individual csv files.

I dont know how to specify in the code, that the program should export the table per pdf file to a csv file that has the same name as the pdf file in the loop with Camelot.

I hope that someone is able to help with some advice on how to proceed from here - thanks in advance.

```py
import camelot
import csv​
import pandas as pd​
import os ​
​
directoryPath = r"PATHFILE"​
os.chdir(directoryPath)​
folderLister = os.listdir(directoryPath)​
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):​
    for name in file:​
        if name.endswith(".pdf"):​
            filename=os.path.join(folders,name)​
            print(filename)​
            print(name)​
            tables=camelot.read_pdf(filename, flavor ="stream")​
            tables = tables[0].df
            tables[0].to_csv(".csv) # I am unsure how to specifiy the program to save a individual csv file with name of the pdf.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use PDF filename, to get CSV filename:

```
csv_filename=filename.replace('.pdf','.csv')

tables[0].to_csv(csv_filename)
```